# how to read null value cell value in java using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can someone post the required Java code showing how to read all cells, including null value cells, in Java using Apache poi. I want to replace any null cell with the value as "blank" on final output.

Sample Excel:

### FirstName SecondName LastName

1. Deepak    Kumar      Pradhan
2. John                 Miller
3. Bhagat    Panigrahy

Sample output:

### FirstName SecondName LastName

1. Deepak    Kumar      Pradhan
2. John      Blank      Miller
3. Bhagat    Panigrahy  Blank

Thanks in advance

Comment: "can you someone post java code how to..." is not an appropriate way to ask a question in stack overflow, this is not a coding service. Please check how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the missing cell policy in your code, either for the workbook as a whole, or when getting a single Cell from a Row with getCell(int, Row.MissingCellPolicy). See the Apache POI API documentation for this:

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#setMissingCellPolicy(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy)

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell(int,%20org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy)